# Crop Square in iOS 8 UIImagepicker off-center

Tags: ios, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller

Has anyone else noticed that in iOS 8 that the square crop tool you get when allowsEditing is set to true is off-center?

For example, on the image, I can't move the square to capture the bottom parts of the image; it keeps getting pushed back up.

[image]

Comment: @iMack.. I have the same issue. Let me know if you could solve this.

The image is not centralized..

http://pbrd.co/1EAeMRv

Answer (score -2):

I have no idea how, but i totally removed "View controller-based status bar appearance" key row (just fully delete this row) in .plist file and it fixed this bug